# Does the function $f:\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\} \to\mathbb R$, defined by (see below), have a limit as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$? .

Tags: real-analysis

Does the function $f:\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\} \to\mathbb R$ defined by $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac  x {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ have a limit as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$?

(Chapter section is on Euclidean Space - Continuous Functions)

I am having trouble even beginning on this one.  I have thought about how to show this for quite some time.  I am not sure if I am forgetting a procedure I may have already learned in a previous course and the chapter section does not have an example.  I am thinking maybe it needs to be approached from continuity using epsilon and delta definitions, or maybe I am overthinking this.  Please show details so that I may understand the approach and the correct process.  Thank you so much.

I was further thinking, you cannot approach this problem from continuity using epsilon and delta definitions as the function is not defined there, and cannot therefore compare the value of the function in (0,0) with the limit, if my understanding is correct

Comment: Hint: Try setting either $x$ or $y$ to 0 and then letting the other variable approach $0$. Do you get the same result for both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you approach $(0,0)$ along the $x$-axis, where $y=0$, you have
$$
\frac x {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac x {\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac x {|x|} \to \begin{cases} 1 & \text{as }x \downarrow 0, \\[10pt] -1 & \text{as }x\uparrow 0. \end{cases}
$$

If you approach $(0,0)$ along the $y$-axis, where $x=0$, you have
$$
\frac x {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0 \to 0 \text{ as }y\to0.
$$

These differing results imply the function does not have a limit at that point.